# Too many quote marks - How would I echo this without closing them up

Tags: php, html

Basically I want to have my spoiler thingy inside an echo, but can't get it to work due to the quotes marks confusing me, hah.

```
echo "<input class='spoilerbutton' type='button' value='Register' onclick='this.value=this.value=='Register'?'Cancel':'Register';'><div class='spoiler'><div>woooohoo hide this text</div></div>";
```

As you can see by the 'register'?'cancel' part, there are quotes that gets closed by one another.

How could I fix this the most simple way? I'm getting too confused, lol.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I can still print it out, can't I? My problem is that I can't echo it because of the ' ' ' ' interfering with eachother.

Comment: for the register part: echo "......onclick=\"....\"";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put HTML inside PHP strings if you can help it. Turn it inside out.

```
if (somecondition) {
    ?>
    <input 
        class='spoilerbutton' 
        type='button' 
        value='Register' 
        onclick="this.value=this.value=='Register'?'Cancel':'Register';">
    <div class='spoiler'>
        <div>woooohoo hide this text</div>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {

}
```

For that matter, don't put JavaScript inside HTML attributes if you can help it.

```
<input 
    class='spoilerbutton' 
    type='button' 
    value='Register'>
<script>
     var input = document.querySelector('input.spoilerbutton')l
     input.addEventListener('click', toggleValue);
     function toggleValue(evt) {
         this.value=this.value=='Register'?'Cancel':'Register';
     }
</script>
```

Comment: What if I need it to be inside an if/else statement?

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop — Then put it inside an if/else statement. (Updated the example in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the quotation marks like so

```
echo "<input class='spoilerbutton' type='button' value='Register' onclick='this.value=this.value==\"Register\"?\"Cancel\":\"Register\";'><div class='spoiler'><div>woooohoo hide this text</div></div>";
```